# Can't change image in link share on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've got a weird problem on my fanpage. I put a link in a post (from shopify)
and it's shows me a carousel. I uploaded custom image (i don't want to have carousel, just single image) and it's impossible to choose it. It's look like:

[image]

The new orange is a custom image. I deleted a 3 fields carousel, now as you can see it's captain america with solo style, but when I'm clicking on the arrow, it's changing to second and third image (custom is fourth) and then...to first.
All the time.

How to make it? Please help me!

Answer (score -1):

this should be due to recent changes by facebook to prevent spam and fake news. Please see e.g.
https://adespresso.com/academy/blog/top-updates-facebook-monthly-need-know-now/

quote: "Facebook is removing the ability to edit a link preview – its image, title, and text – before sharing a link on the platform."

Answer (score -1):

If you are a Shopify store owner, you can try our [Shopify App - SEO Product Optimizer](https://apps.shopify.com/seo-product-optimizer). You can set a custom link preview image for all pages in your Shopify store.